# C programming with files in different modes?

Tags: c, file, append, fopen

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];

    fp=fopen("test.txt","w");

    printf("File test.txt in w mode\n");
    fprintf(fp,"Template string 1:\n");

    fputs("Template string 2:",fp);
    printf("File test.txt is created at local path\n\n");
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
    printf("\n\nFile test.txt in r mode\n");
    fscanf(fp,"%s",buff);
    printf("The content of the file test.txt using fscanf() is:\n%s\n",buff);

    fgets(buff,255,(FILE *)fp);
    printf("The content of the file test.txt using fgets() is :\n%s\n",buff);

    fgets(buff,255,(FILE *)fp);
    printf("The content of the file using fgets() is :\n%s\n",buff);
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("test.txt","a");
    printf("\n\nFile test.txt in a mode\n");
    fprintf(fp,"Template String 3:\n");
    fgets(buff,255,(FILE *)fp);
    printf("After append %s\n",buff);
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("test.txt","r+");
    printf("File test.txt in r+ mode\n");
    fgets(buff,255,(FILE *)fp);
    printf("\n\nThe content of the file test.txt in r+ mode is:\n%s\n",buff);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I have the above code which i understood. I have a doubt that when i append the string "Template string 3:" my fp adds the content to file `test.txt` at the end of the file and after adding fp should points to the end of file(i hope) but if i use `fgets` to read the content of the file from fp to the buff what it should have. Can anyone explain what is that happening at this point of time.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: The casts of the variable defined as `FILE*fp;` using `(FILE *)fp` are "harmless" but ludicrous.

Answer (score 0):

The C library function `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.

This is why the last part of your code shows only the first line of the file. And the reason why you don't get an output for the `printf("After append %s\n",buff);` is that the file pointer is located at `EOF` at this time.

When you `cat` the file you'll see that all the lines are there.